# PHP: Unexpected behavior: foreach... {$array['country'][] = $value['country']}

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

Why does the operator

`$array['country'][]` return what logically would be `$array[]['country']`?

What I am saying is this. If you want to extract from a MySQL array, the value of ['country'] for every row, [1],[2]...[n], you have to use

```
$array['country'][]
```

despite fact that they are ordered as

```
$array['row#']['country']
```

Is this because PHP is reading something backwards, or because I am just lacking some fundamental array information?

FULL-ish code here

```
$result = array();
foreach($data as $value){

   $array['country'][] = $value['country'];
   $array['report'][] = $value['report'];
}
$data = $array;
```

Let me know if I am just dumb... I can't really grasp why this is working this way.

Comment: What do you have in `$data` before entering the `foreach`? i.e. what does var_dump($data) look like?

Comment: I am away from my Linux machine now, but it is just a basic while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){$data[]=$row;}

Comment: Also, why are you defining `$result` as an empty array, but then, you do not touch it in the rest of the code?

Comment: I guess what I thought I was doing to make things simple was to define an array that I could use later outside of the while-loop. It seems to work, just has some paradoxical behavior.

Comment: So each element in $data is an associative array itself, and you are trying to sort of transpose it to another array in which column names are the keys and each holds values for that column? I do not see what the question is then.

Comment: Well my question is about the notation. I am kind of understanding better though, through the answer that Lawrence gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the operator
>
> $array['country'][]
>
> return what
>   logically would be
>   $array[]['country']?

It is because *you* are constructing the array in that way:

If you use `$array['country'][] = $value['country'];`, you are adding a new value to the sub-array which is part of the containing array under the `country` key. So it will be mapped to `$array['country'][]`, you cannot expect otherwise.

If you *want it* to map to `array[]['country']`, then (using part of code from 
@Lawrence's answer), you'd have to add the new values using explicit numerical indexes as the key:

```
SELECT country,report from yourdb
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $array[$i]['country'][] = $row['country'];
  $array[$i]['report'][] = $row['report'];
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: I think it was just my poor understanding of how PHP treats nested arrays that is tripping me up. Thanks for showing me that. That let me understand how I can name the keys: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  
  $array['report'][$i." ".$row['country']] = $row['report'];
  $array['report'][$i." ".$row['region']] = $row['report'];
  $i++;
}
print_r($array);`

Answer (score 2):

```
get an id from the db

    SELECT id,country,report from yourdb

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $array['country'][$row['id']] = $row['country'];
     $array['report'][$row['id']] = $row['report'];
    }


create an id

    SELECT country,report from yourdb
    $i=0
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $array['country'][$i] = $row['country'];
     $array['report'][$i] = $row['report'];
    $i++
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `$data` has been built by you using a loop like what you pasted in the comments (`while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){$data[]=$row;}`) then my answer would be because that's exactly what you asked PHP to do.

The notion `$data[] = some-value-here` means take that value and add it with to the end of `$data` array with an auto-generated key I just don't care. That is, PHP will basically see what the last item's key is, add 1 and use that as the key for the item you are adding to the array.

So what you are doing with that loop is building an array whose keys are numbers starting from 0 and incrementing (+1 each cycle, this is the `[]` effect) and using these keys for the rows you are getting off the database result set.

If you want to access `$data` in the way you described, then you have to change the way you are building it. See [Lawrence Cherone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003045/php-unexpected-behavior-foreach-arraycountry-valuecountry/6003152#6003152) for that.